# Using find -name with tar in a bash script, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: find, tar

I'm trying to learn how to use `bash` scripts; I have googled answers but can not find any answer to my problem.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tar.gz
DESDIR=home/pi/backups
SRC=home/pi/backuplist.txt
find -iname '*.orig' -o -iname '*.py' > home/pi/backuplist.txt
tar -zcvf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRC
```

when I run this it doesn't create the `backuplist.txt` so there is no result to use with `tar`.

i tried using `find -iname` directly with `tar` in a pipeline but just got the response `-iname command does not exist`.

When I use `find` to output first in the terminal and then use `tar` it works.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: ... and it's assumed that it's run from the root directory (`/`)? Otherwise there may be an issue creating the output file(s). Do you get errors?

Comment: oops, that typo isn't in the actual script tho

Comment: yes a whole bunch. home/pi/backuplist.txt: The file does not exist. 'ckups/backup-apr-16-17.tar.gz: Function "open" failed' tar (Child):error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Once you get the `backuplist.txt` file, I presume you will have to use it with the `-I` flag to `tar`, otherwise you'll just create a `tar` archive with the backup list file.

Comment: when i use find in the terminal the -iname works, i tried to change to jus -name but that doesnt seem to work either

Comment: yes, there are 3 *.py and 4*.orig files

Comment: Show the exact command that you gave on the terminal & which purportedly generates results.

Comment: If this script doesn't match the script you're actually using [please fix the typos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/359345/edit). Otherwise we may end up trying to address errors that don't actually exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main issues with this script:

1. The paths are relative.  This means that when you run it, it is assumed that `home/pi` exists in the *current directory*.  I have a feeling that all instances of `home/pi` in the script should be changed to `/home/pi`.
2. The `tar` command is probably meant to back up the files in the `backuplist.txt` file.  The way it's written now, you'll get a `tar` archive containing the `backuplist.txt` file itself and nothing else.  If you meant to read the *contents* of that file, use `tar -zcvf "$DESDIR/$FILENAME" -T "$SRC"`.
3. There are also unquoted variables in the script.

Here's what I think you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIME="$(date +%b-%d-%y)"
FILENAME="backup-$TIME.tar.gz"
DESDIR="/home/pi/backups"
SRC="/home/pi/backuplist.txt"

find /home/pi -iname '*.orig' -o -iname '*.py' >"$SRC"
tar -zcvf "$DESDIR/$FILENAME" -T "$SRC"
```

The `/home/pi` on the `find` command line is a wild guess.  Without it, I assume GNU `find` would use the current directory.

Comment: that made a difference, the error messages that i had Before is gone, now it says find: search path must come Before: home/pi/backuplist.txt

Comment: @MårtenAhlberg Are you using `find /home/pi ...` as I wrote? ... and absolute paths everywhere?

Comment: i wrote it in again and it must have been something i missed the first time, it works like a charm now. Thank you so much, without your help i probably would be sitting here in a year from now still trying to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this slightly different script will address your original desire to have the list of files piped directly into `tar`.

I've quoted variables where they are used, and replaced backticks `` `...` `` with the modern `$(...)` construct.

Finally, I've assumed you want this to run from `/`, so that the paths you've used can exist.

```
#!/bin/bash
WHEN=$(date +%b-%d-%y)
FILENAME="backup-$WHEN.tar.gz"
DESDIR=/home/pi/backups
SRC=/home/pi/backuplist.txt

mkdir -p "$DESDIR"

cd /
find -iname '*.orig' -o -iname '*.py' |
    tee "$SRC" |
    tar zcvf "$DESDIR/$FILENAME" --no-recursion --verbatim-files-from --files-from -
```

You can completely omit the two lines referencing `$SRC` if you don't need to create the list of files during the backup process.